# how to create React Context for a function value without re-rendering all the time

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-context

I am using React with hooks (no class components).

I currently have code like this:

```js
function useTimerange()
{
    const [tr, setTr] = useState(defaultRange);

    function setCustomRange(range)
    {
        setTr(range);
    }

    return {tr, setCustomRange};
}

const ContextSetCustomTimerange = React.createContext(undefined);

function MyComponent(props)
{
    const {tr, setCustomRange} = useTimerange();

    return (
        <>
            <TimeRangePicker selectedRange={tr}/>
            <ContextSetCustomTimerange.Provider value={setCustomRange}>
              <MyChildComponent/>
            </ContextSetCustomTimerange.Provider>
        </>
    );
}
```

The problem is on this line:

```js
<ContextSetCustomTimerange.Provider value={setCustomRange}>
```

since the value being passed is a function that is recreated each time MyComponent renders, it will cause the Context provider to re-render all its consumers every time.

What is the best way to prevent this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `useCallback` from react hooks. https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usecallback

```
import { useCallback } from 'react'

function useTimerange()
{
    const [tr, setTr] = useState(defaultRange);
    const setCustomRange = useCallback((range) => {
      setTr(range);
    }, [])

    return {tr, setCustomRange};
}
```

or may be just return direct `setTr`

`return {tr, setCustomRange: setTr};`

Answer (score 0):

The performance issue here is that if `setCustomRange` changes it's reference it will trigger a render an all consumers for your context, since react is comparing references.

I think `useCallback` with [], like Giang mentions, will do it at it seems like the best idea.

You can also pass a state to the provider value and put the function on the state; since the state reference is kept and when react compares the old value with the new value it will detect the're the same and leave the thing alone.